# How can i check if my datetime is expired or about to expire in 3 days

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

In my database I have datetime in this format:

```
2016-4-4 02:04:57
```

**How can I check following:**

```
1. How can I check if my database date is about to expire in next 3 days?
2. How can I check if my database date is expired 3 days ago?
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I tried something like this
if(strtotime($mydate) > strtotime('-3 days')) {
echo 'three days old';
}

But i am not sure if it is right

Comment: I can't edit it due to lack of changes in my suggested edit but I'm pretty sure code formatting should only be used for code and not to emphasis text.

Answer (score 4):

Try and change with this,

```
SELECT `exp_date`,IF(`exp_date` <= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY ,1,0) as expired,
       IF(`exp_date` >= NOW() AND `exp_date` < NOW() + INTERVAL 3 DAY ,1,0) as expiring 
       FROM `table_name`
```

And check with `1` as found and `0` as not found.

You can also try with tow separate query for each condition with where clause.

Comment: it seems to be work perfectly. I am new with mysql how can we run this query separately for each result?

Comment: Somehow this is fine, But my goal was to check only date which is expired 3 days ago, it shows all dates which is expired 3 days ago.